SQL optimization improve efficiency | filter data on non primary key column
I have a SQL Teradata table with 4 columns. Cust_id & Act_num are indexed columns, and Date is not indexed.
I need to filter the data on the DATE column.
Select 
    Cust_id,
    Act_num,
    Date,
    Max(score) Max_Score
from
    table_name
where 
    date >= 1240601
group by 
    1, 2, 3

The query takes a long time to run, as it is filtering on the non-indexed column, and when I run that query to retrieve data for more than 6 months, it shows error insufficient spool space.
I have read only access and limited spool space which cannot be changed.
Please suggest ways to optimize the query. I already tried self join and exists

You can try retrieve data as batches  like where date >=1240601 and date<1240901, next as where date >=1240901 and date<1241201 and so on. Your query takes filtered rows where date >=1240601 then spool to sort on(Cust_id,Act_num,Date) and group by ...

Work with your DBAs.  First suggestion is to ensure stats are collected and current for the column you are trying to filter on.  BTW, are you trying to use dates in teradata's native format?  There is no benefit to doing so, and it's much more readable to use  date '2024-06-01'

You can split the query into smaller timeframes if your spool space is insufficient. Try using this query:
-- Query for first 3 months
INSERT INTO temp_table
SELECT 
    Cust_id, Act_num, Date, MAX(score) AS Max_Score
FROM 
    table_name
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN 1240601 AND 1240901
GROUP BY 
    Cust_id, Act_num, Date;

-- Query for next 3 months
INSERT INTO temp_table
SELECT 
    Cust_id, Act_num, Date, MAX(score) AS Max_Score
FROM 
    table_name
WHERE 
    date BETWEEN 1240902 AND 1241201
GROUP BY 
    Cust_id, Act_num, Date;

-- Combine results from temp_table
SELECT * FROM temp_table;

Let me know if this helps.

Create a  a Btree index  on the date columnn :
create index idx_date_column_name on tablename(date_columnname);

Btree indexes are optimised for range values and ordering and range value filter  where date >= 1240601 is present in your query
